# Getting connection timeout exception in android while trying to get response from server

Tags: android, connection, connection-timeout

I have developed a android app which connect to server and access xml from server using url. I am Using HttpUrlConncetion to connect. I have written this connection code in a jar file and My app is using this jar to connect to server.This app is working properly when i am using emulator but when i install this app on my mobile then it throw exception.

I have added intenet permission in manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Exception is

```
Connection timed out 
org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.connect(Native Method)
dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedNetworkSystem.connect(BlockGuard.java:388)
org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:236)
org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:470)
java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:1055)
org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.<init>           (HttpConnection.java:106)
org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.<init>   (HttpConnection.java:79)org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:353)org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:120)org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getHttpConnection
(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:316)org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.makeConnection

(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:298)
org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect

(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:236)
com.tracking.jar.XmlDownLoader.openConnection(XmlDownLoader.java:46)
com.tracking.jar.XmlDownLoader.downLoadXml(XmlDownLoader.java:18)
com.tracking.jar.BusDetails.getProviderRouteBeanList

(BusDetails.java:179)
com.vehicletracking.GetProviderRouteBeanListAsyncTask.doInBackground

(GetProviderRouteBeanListAsyncTask.java:17)
com.vehicletracking.GetProviderRouteBeanListAsyncTask.doInBackground

(GetProviderRouteBeanListAsyncTask.java:1)
android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:216)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:337)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:169)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1119)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:612)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1052)
```

My mobile is rooted and i have in install app call blocker app which block incoming and out going call.

My connection code is:

```
public String downLoadXml(String urlString) throws Exception{
    urlString = urlString.replace(" ", "%20");
    String xfStr = "";
    HttpURLConnection httpConn = null;
    try{
        httpConn = openConnection(urlString);
        InputStream in = httpConn.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(in);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String str =null;

        while((str = br.readLine())!= null){
            xfStr = xfStr + str;
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        throw e;
    }
    finally{
        if(httpConn!=null){
            httpConn.disconnect();
        }
    }
    return xfStr;
}

private HttpURLConnection openConnection(String urlString) throws IOException{
    URL url  = new URL(urlString);
    HttpURLConnection httpConn = null;
    httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
    httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
    httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    httpConn.setConnectTimeout(60000);
    httpConn.connect();
    return httpConn;
}
```

Comment: Please check the address of server is it right.. ?? Are you testing it on local network.

Comment: check the url from your browser first..

Comment: @TGMCians yes address of server is right and i m able to access it from browser

Comment: @Raj url is woriking from browser

Comment: @Prithvi Singh Rathore are mobile is connected to internet and are you testing in lan...

Comment: Try opening the url from your mobile's browser or the emulator's browser wherever you are testing this app on.

Comment: @TGMCians yes mobile is connected to internet and  my emulator is in lan but i m testing on mobile where lan is not available

Comment: @Enigma url is working on mobile's browser

Comment: `urlString = urlString.replace(" ", "%20");` This is strange. So your URL has spaces or your URL has `?key=value&key=value...` query parameters. In such cases you have to do `"key=" + URLEncoder.encode(value, "UTF-8") + "&key=" + URLEncoder.encode(value, "UTF-8")` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Genius try this,

```
try {
                HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
                int timeoutConnection = 3000;
                int socketTimeoutConnection = 5000;
                HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams,
                        timeoutConnection);
                HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams,
                        socketTimeoutConnection);
                DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                client.setParams(httpParams);
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(postedScholarshipUrl);
                HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(httpGet);
                StatusLine statusLine = httpResponse.getStatusLine();
                 int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
                if (statusCode == 200) {
                    ResponseHandler<String> response = new BasicResponseHandler();
                    serverStr = client.execute(httpGet, response);
                    int myArray = new JSONArray(serverStr);
                    arrayLength = myArray.length();
                } else {
                    showDialog(connectionDown);
                }

            } catch (SocketTimeoutException bug) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Socket Timeout", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (ConnectTimeoutException bug) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connection Timeout", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (Exception bug) {
                bug.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure mobile is connected with internet.

You should check for Network connection before executing your HTTP request. Write this code in try catch block.